# HTML5: JavaScript объект textTrack

Tags: javascript, html5, online-video

### Браузеры Фаерфокс и Хромиум. Тег video и вложенный track

1. Каждый объект **TextTrack** имеет свойство **cues**, которое является списком **TextTrackCueList**, содержащим объекты **VTTCue** (все метки текущего трека).
2. Каждый объект **VTTCue** имеет свойство **track**, которое является объектом **TextTrack**. Этот **TextTrack** — смотрим первый пункт.

Если представить, как дерево

```
TextTrack
  cues[0]
    track
      cues[0]
        track ... и так до неопределенной глубины.
```

## HTML

```
<video width="400" height="225" id="myVideo" preload="metadata" controls>
    <source src="my-video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
    <track src="track.vtt" default="true" kind="subtitles"  srclang="en" label="English">
</video>
```

Можно открыть инструменты разработчика в браузере, или пройтись скриптом в глубину дерева.

## JavaScript

```
<script>
var headTrack;

// После загрузки окна получаем объект трека
// Навешиваем на него обработчик
window.onload = function() {
       var headTrack = myVideo.textTracks[0];
       headTrack.addEventListener('cuechange', getAllTracks);
       console.log(myVideo.textTracks);
};

// Когда браузер заходит в метку, запускаем основную функцию
function getAllTracks(event) {
     var currentTrack = event.target;
     getHoleTracks(currentTrack);
}

// Счётчик, чтобы не было бесконечной рекурсии
var counter = 0;

// Извлекаем cues из textTrack
// Извлекаем track из VTTCue
function getHoleTracks(textTrack) {
     counter++;
     var firstCue = textTrack.cues[0];
     var cuesTrack = firstCue.track;

     // Вывод в консоль для наглядности
     console.log(counter);
     console.log('firstCue' + firstCue);
     console.log('cuesTrack' + cuesTrack);

     // Если последний TextTrack содержит cues, повторяем
     // Ограничимся сотней выводов
     if (cuesTrack.cues[0] && (counter < 100) ) {
        getHoleTracks(cuesTrack);
     }
}
</script>
```

**Вопросы**

- Это что, кроличья нора без дна? Баг или фича?
- Влияет ли нагрузку браузера такое дерево объектов или он как-то оптимизирует не создавая его на всю глубину?
- Или это я что-то неправильно понимаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство track - всего лишь ссылка на родительский обект типа TextTrack. Проверить это очень легко: нужно добавить какое-нибудь дополнительное свойство в myVideo.textTracks[0] и посмотреть добавилось ли оно во всех вложенных объектах (добавилось). Получается, что никакой кроличьей норы нет - вы ходили по кругу

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, я слишком буквально воспринимаю визуальную картинку из инструментов разработчика в браузере. Всегда с трудом понимаю ссылки и указатели. Не могу представить визуальную аналогию.

[image: Скриншот консоли инструментов разработчика]

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая структура данных **связный список**. На `js` его не сложно реализовать, причем возьмем частный случай, двунаправленный связный список.
Это список, у которого каждый элемент имеет ссылку на родительский элемент и дочерний

Создадим такой список из двух объектов:

```
const obj1 = { value : 1, parent: null, child: null }
const obj2 = { value : 2, parent: null, child: null }

// свяжем эти два объекта
obj1.child = obj2
obj2.parent = obj1
```

И так мы создали **циклические ссылки**, потому что св-во `parent` у `obj2` ссылается на `obj1`, у которого есть св-во `child`, которое ссылается на `obj2`

Как это выглядит в консоли:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Казалось, бы, это должно занимать бесконечно много памяти, но движок браузера не такой глупый. Поэтому он хранит не сам объект ( его копию ), а, грубо говоря, адрес в памяти, пройдя по которому можно получить нужные данные. Тем самым мы не плодим бесконечные сущности, а используем ссылки для доступа к объектам в св-вах.

Так же и с DOM структурой, у каждого элемент есть св-во `parentNode`, которое ссылается на родительский элемент, в свою очередь у родительского элемента есть св-во `children`, коллекция дочерних элементов, которые ссылаются на его детей, у которых св-во `parentNode` ссылается обратно на родительский элемент)))

По понятным причинам, такие объекты сложно представить в виде `JSON` ( ошибка как бы намекает )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот теперь я вроде бы понял. Сделал подобное в файловой системе. 
Папка Parent содержит папку Children. 
В папке Children — ссылка на папку Parent.